# Java Matcher start in respect to line

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a program to check if a list of keys are present in the long text.

I consume my text and feed it to the matcher in 1000 rows as a single String separated by \n new line symbol.

In case of matching I call match.start() to get the position of matched symbol. But it returns me the position not in regard new line but like the single string.

Here's text example:

```
The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes
by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle
(#15 in our series by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle)

Copyright laws are changing all over the world. Be sure to check the
copyright laws for your country before downloading or redistributing
this or any other Project Gutenberg eBook.
```

I consume it using this method:

```
public String readLinesBatch(int startLine, int step, String file) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file))) {
        return lines.skip(startLine)
                .limit(step).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Exception while reading lines: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

After that I feed it to the Matcher method:

```
public List<OffsetResult> matchV1(String source, Integer line) {
    List<OffsetResult> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher match = Pattern.compile(String.join("|", keys))
            .matcher(source);
    while (match.find()) {
        int offsetStart = match.start();
        getLine(source, match.start());
        result.add(new OffsetResult(match.group(), line, offsetStart));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The result I receive if `Arthur` is present in my keys is next:

```
Arthur=[charOffset=72]
```

But what I need is it to be **7**. Because `Arthur` world occurs on a 2 line at the 7th position.

I googled and found nothing regarding this issue.
Does anyone have some ideas?
Thanks in advance!

UPD: my OffsetResult class

```
public class OffsetResult {

    private String key;
    private Integer lineOffset;
    private Integer charOffset;
}
```

Comment: Please describe your class `OffsetResult`.

Comment: Hi @HeapUnderStop! I updated my question with OffsetResult

Answer (score 1):

You can either split the string then find position in every of them and take e.g. first

```
Arrays.stream(input.split(String.format("%n")))
    .map(s -> someMethodReturningPositionOrNull(s))
    .filter(s -> s != null)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(someDefaultValueOrNull)
```

or extend your regular expression to get last new line character just before searched string (then you also need to take care about string occuring before first new line character)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. But I was wondering maybe there's a solution without splitting the string. Because right now I have a working prototype with passing each string line. And it works fine. But I wanted to find solution with providing 1000 lines as a single string. To speed up the process